# Sql - Use the biggest value to select other data

Tags: sql, mysql

I've a big doubt on the way to retrieve the biggest value of a table and use it in another query.

Consider this :

```
CREATE TABLE people
(
    peopleID int NOT NULL,
    cityID int NOT NULL
)
```

The following request gives me the number of people per city

```
SELECT peopleID, COUNT(*)
FROM people
GROUP BY cityID
```

Suppose I want the people list of the biggest city, I would write this request like :

```
SELECT people.peopleID, people.cityID
FROM people,
(
SELECT cityID, COUNT(*) AS "people_count"
FROM people
GROUP BY cityID
) g
WHERE people.cityID = g.cityID
HAVING people_count = MIN(people_count)
```

but doesn't work, what's the best way to achieve this request?

Thanks :)

Comment: I would a solution that is database independant, only pure SQL programming :D

Comment: There is no such thing as "pure SQL" -- ANSI isn't impelemented on any database in entirety.

Comment: @OMG Ponies - Well, technically, one could say that "pure SQL" is restricted to statements supported in one of the ISO specifications. However, that's only good for academic exercises. The odds are high that it won't work in one or more database products and given that, it comes down to whether you want something you can use in a real product or something you can use to win an argument against Celko.

Comment: Just write all examples using [SqLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) as your reference SQL database.  It should be pretty easy to transition their knowledge of databases from SqLite to whatever they need to use, and this has the advantage that anyone who is trying to learn can play with it at home or in class without setup work or cost.  You can, of course, point out some of the special specific where the differences are significant.  Note that there are some important DB-specific features available on some DBs that people using them ought to learn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This technique should work in most databases:

```
SELECT peopleID
FROM people
WHERE cityID =
(
    SELECT cityID
    FROM people
    GROUP BY cityID
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
```

LIMIT 1 is not standard SQL (the standard states that you should use FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY). See here for a list of how to fetch only the first row in a variety of databases:

- [Select (SQL) - Result limits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28SQL%29#Result_limits)

---

Edit: I misunderstood your question. I thought you meant what is a sensible way to perform this query that can easily be modified to work in almost any SQL database. But it turns out what you actually want to know is how to write the query so that it will work using *exactly* the same syntax in all databases. Even random databases that no-one uses that don't even properly support the SQL standard. In which case you can *try* this but I'm sure you can find a database where even this doesn't work:

```
SELECT peopleID, cityID
FROM people
WHERE cityID = (
    SELECT MAX(cityID)
    FROM (
        SELECT cityID
        FROM people
        GROUP BY cityID
        HAVING COUNT(*) =
        (
            SELECT MAX(cnt) FROM
            (
                SELECT cityID, COUNT(*) AS cnt
                FROM people
                GROUP BY cityID
            ) T1
        )
    ) T2
)
```

Comment: On Sybase, there is not LIMIT or TOP ! So doesn't work on ALL databases :/

Comment: That only works in MySQL..OP asked for a DB Indpendent Solution (in the comments)

Comment: @Arnaud F.: Not all databases support standard SQL so that's not going to be possible, I'm afraid.

Comment: So just give me the best way pleaaaaaaaaaaase ... (possible to avoid LIMIT !?)

Comment: @Arnaud F. Can you tell me the list of databases you want it to work on? That would be far easier than me trying to guess your requirements.

Comment: I've no list, I train someone to the use of "pure" SQL and I've the good idea to ask "Give me the list of people of the most populated city", thinking it was easy to write it whitout knowing each databases functionality...

Comment: (but database used is MySQL, so above request works, but not sure that my trainee will use MySQL later ;)

Comment: @Arnaud F. What is "pure" SQL? If you mean ANSI SQL then you should use FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY as I stated in my answer. The problem though is that currently very few databases support the standard syntax.

Comment: DB2 is the only to currently support FETCH FIRST ROWS

Comment: I really love the way to achieve a request that seems to be so simple when said...

Comment: @Arnaud F - Just because a problem is easy to state does not mean that it is easy to solve. In fact, I find the opposite is typically true. "I just want this bridge from here to here. On the map, it's only three inches. It should be simple. Just build a bridge from NY to London."

Comment: @Thomas: But it's easy to say "lead into gold"! :)